# How to navigate through javascript links in selenium(scrapy) and then come back to the original page?

Tags: javascript, selenium, scrapy

I'm having troubles while dealing with pages that contain javascript link. The problem is the page contains list of cities which have javascript in their links. Now I've to navigate to each link one by one, scrape some information and then come back to the list and move to the next city and continue scraping.

The problem is after clicking on the javascript links using selenium web driver, when I navigate back to the list page the response is lost and I get error like :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element:     {"method":"id","selector":"some_id"}'
```

Is there any way around ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, javascript only handle posts for ajax requests. You just have to understand what the javascript is doing and reimplement that same logic within Scrapy, without any need for Selenium.
For that, just use the Chrome Developer tools or Firefox Firebug.
If you need variables that are set in javascript, I guess you can use a javascript engine like v8 (in a wrapper like pyV8).

Do you have an example that we can help you on ?

Comment: Thank You for your comment. I'll give pyV8 a try as the javascript present in the website do set variables. If it doesn't works ,I'll come back with an enxample and the code that I'm working on.